# Visio workflow visualization in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-workflow

Can you please confirm that we don't have Visio visualization of new workflows in Sharepoint 2013? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes. Visio visualization is not available for 2013 wokflows